# Как сохранить данные в фрагменте!!! при выходе из приложения?

Tags: android

Необходимо сохранять введеные в `EditText` данные при выходе из приложения. Есть реализация для `Acivity`, но если использовать в фрагменте (с некоторыми поправками) приложение вылетает.

```
public class Setting extends Fragment {

public static Setting newInstance() {
    Setting fragment = new Setting();

    return fragment;
}

Button btnSave, btnLoad;
EditText etText, etText2, etText3;
SharedPreferences sPref, sPref2, sPref3;

final String SAVED_TEXT_BD = "saved_textBD";
final String SAVED_TEXT2_BD = "saved_textBD2";
final String SAVED_TEXT3_BD = "saved_textBD3";

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_setting, null);

    Button button = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(getContext(),SettingBD.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

  etText = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.editText1);
  etText2 = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.editText2);
  etText3 = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.editText3);

  btnSave = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.save);
  btnSave.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener)this);

  btnLoad = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.load);
  btnLoad.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener)this);

  loadText();

  return v;
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.save:
            saveText();
            break;
        case R.id.load:
            loadText();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

void saveText() { /*схранение данных*/
    sPref = this.getActivity().getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    sPref2 = this.getActivity().getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    sPref3 = this.getActivity().getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sPref.edit();
    SharedPreferences.Editor ed2 = sPref2.edit();
    SharedPreferences.Editor ed3 = sPref3.edit();
    ed.putString(SAVED_TEXT_BD, etText.getText().toString());
    ed2.putString(SAVED_TEXT2_BD,etText2.getText().toString());
    ed2.putString(SAVED_TEXT3_BD,etText3.getText().toString());
    ed.commit();
    ed2.commit();
    ed3.commit();
}

void loadText() { /*загрузка данных*/
    sPref = this.getActivity().getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    sPref2 = this.getActivity().getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    sPref3 = this.getActivity().getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String savedText = sPref.getString(SAVED_TEXT_BD, "");
    String savedText2 = sPref2.getString(SAVED_TEXT2_BD, "");
    String savedText3 = sPref3.getString(SAVED_TEXT3_BD, "");
    etText.setText(savedText);
    etText2.setText(savedText2);
    etText3.setText(savedText3);
}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    saveText();
}



public String getMyData() {
    return SAVED_TEXT_BD;
}
```

Ошибка:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.wb.myapplication, PID: 1326
              java.lang.NullPointerException
                  at com.wb.myapplication.Setting.onCreateView(Setting.java:44)
                  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2346)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1428)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1759)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1827)
                  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2596)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2383)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2338)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2245)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:703)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: если вылетает - прикладывайте к вопросу стектрейс при падении приложения

Comment: Эта сами ошибки в консоли вашей среды разработки

Comment: @pavlofff , готово

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените `getView()` на `v`, вероятно в этом месте ошибка, так как `view` ещё не установлена для фрагмента. Ещё замените

```
btnSave.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener)this);
btnLoad.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener)this);
```

на

```
btnSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            saveText();     
        }
    });

btnLoad.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            loadText();        
        }
    });
```

соответственно

А вообще посмотрите на строку `Setting.java:44`, там ошибка

Comment: Да, это помогло. Спасибо